# DXA Link resolver issue

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.6

We have a Page with Component A (a container Component) associated with a static template which has another Component B as a Linked Component field. In the associated model for B, I have created a field to serve URL like:

```
@SemanticProperty("_self")
private String url;
```

URL field is always empty, even if the Page containing parent Component A is published. There is a dynamic Component Template present for the Component B. Here is the diagram of page AB where B is present as a linked component:

[image]

I am mapping model for page CD where B is also present which has the url field with empty value:

[image]

Can anyone suggest if I am missing anything?

Comment: is B also attached to some page?

Comment: @Raj, I have updated my question with information.

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain some more detail about the actual Schemad and models for the Components C, D and B?

Comment: Mukesh, your link property is set to _self. This means that this link will be resolved as a link of the component itself (not as a link to the component you are linking to). What happens if you change "_self" to the actual schema field name of the componentlink field ?

Comment: Harald, in main model A it is added as actual schema field name as a type of view model of B and in view model url is defind with "_self" semantic property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite your pictures, the structure of your View Models (and how they map to Components in CM) is not quite clear to me. For example: what does "Component as embedded field" mean? Do you mean you have an embedded View Model mapped to an embedded field?

Regardless, it seems to me you want to get a link to Component B resolved. DXA link resolving will resolve a Component link to a URL of **a published Page which contains a Component Presentation for the linked Component**.

In your description, I don't see that you have such a Page, which could explain why the link does not resolve.

In case Component B is a Multimedia Component, you may want to resolve a link to its published Binary content instead. In that case, you should make the property of type `MediaItem` (or a subclass).

Comment: Hi Rick, this sounds a answer for my question. I was also suspecting that without a direct component presentation with the component it can't be resolved.